# Is that possible to link a huge library within small memory?

Tags: qt, mingw, ld

I've tried several times to cross-compile Qt4.8.2 with mingw32 4.7 on my poor little linux box , which only has 2GB mem,all failed because of the memory limitation. The mingw ld just keeps swallowing the memory until its belly explode. I just want to ask if it is even possible to link such big-ass lib within such a small memory. If it's definitely a no-go, I'd have to resort to some other approaches. Thanks in advance.

~~~~~

Haha! Finally, I found the answer. I just need to temporarily increase my swap memory by creating a swap file on the harddrive. The specific steps will be shown as below:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/swapfile bs=1M count=2048 #create a 2GB big emptyfile
sudo mkswap /mnt/swapfile #format it as a swapfile
sudo swapon /mnt/swapfile #turn on the newly created swap
#... build your big-ass package ...
sudo swapoff /mnt/swapfile #turn off the swap. That means your swap space will be reassigned to your originally arranged swap partion on your HD
```

Happy hacking! ;)

Comment: QT is modular, you can install QT on several micro-PC for creating fully featured touch interfaces and probably you can install QT on your machine too, you have to play with the configuration options before compiling the library.

Comment: @axis The compiling is totally okay, it's just the linking which keeps failing.

Comment: are you compiling for Windows under Linux and especting that a Windows ELF file will be linked against your linux application ? Also playing with the configuration means that you need to make a selection of modules that you are going to use and leave out the rest.

Comment: Yes. I have mingw cross compiler installed on my linux box, I build qt using mingw cross compiler just in order to add it into my cross-compiling environment. I've alrealy successfully built and installed a lot of packages into this environment, qt is the only exception so far.